# Can you automate ui based web app with appium?

Tags: user-interface, automation, appium, ui-automation

I have to automate an UI of web application. I also need to automate an UI in mobile. Does Appium supports both the platform ???
Anyone with knowledge of Appium can comment down below.

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about UI automated tests. Use Appium for mobile in that case, and Selenium for the web app.

Comment: Is there any free automation tool that can support both testing of web app and mobile app which are not cloud-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Appium works perfectly fine for hybrid (native + web) mobile apps:

```java
// assuming we have a set of capabilities
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
}
driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[1]); // set context to WEBVIEW_1

//do some web testing
String myText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".green_button")).click();

driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

// do more native testing if we want

driver.quit();
```

More details are available in [docs](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/)